# Friend declarations: Is this a bug in clang?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, language-lawyer, name-lookup

§3.4.1/3 has the following example:

```
typedef int f;
namespace N
{
    struct A
    {
        friend void f(A &);
        operator int();
        void g(A a)
        {
            int i = f(a);
        }
    };
}
```

Which compiles without errors (see [live example](http://rextester.com/DCFIX79502)) as the compiler doesn't see the friend declaration `N::A::f(A&)` in the ordinary lookup for the name `f` in the declaration `int i = f(a);` and this is correct according to §7.3.1.2/3.

§7.3.1.2/3 (emphasis is mine):

> Every name first declared in a namespace is a member of that
>   namespace. If a friend declaration in a nonlocal class first declares
>   a class or function the friend class or function is a member of the
>   innermost enclosing namespace. The name of the friend is not found by
>   unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or by qualified lookup (3.4.3) until a
>   matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope (**either
>   before or after the class definition granting friendship**).

Now if we include the declarations

```
struct A;
void f(A&);
```

In the snippet above in `namespace N`, **before** the `struct A`, the code will correctly emit an error (see [live example](http://rextester.com/OUBS81834)), as now the function `::f(A&)` is found by ordinary lookup for the name `f` in the expression `int i = f(a);` and this is in accordance with §7.3.1.2/3.

However, if we include the declaration

```
void f(A&);
```

In `namespace N`, **after** the `struct A`, the code surprisingly doesn't emit any error, see [live example](http://rextester.com/CLT93411).

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that it's because the *implementation of `A::g()`* precedes the declaration of `f`'s prototype.  If you move the implementation out of the class and after the declaration of `f` I'd expect you to get an error then.  The spec is only talking about whether the declaration of `f` comes before or after the *friend declaration*; in order for the *implementation* of `A::g()` to find the `f` function, it must be declared prior to the implementation.

Comment: Why do you think it's a bug? At the time `f` is used in `A::g()`, the only definition found by name lookup is the typedef.

Comment: Doesn't §3.4.1/8 apply here? The name must be declared before its use within the member function. If you do that, it [fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfe8a96d2c80ccf0)

Comment: @cdhowie I can accept your argument, but then, wouldn't §7.3.1.2/3 need to be amended?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil No, because that section doesn't seem to be about locating the function *when it is called* but simply the relative order of the friend and function declarations.  To me this reads "you can declare a friend function before or after the declaration of the actual function that is being made a friend."  I don't think it means "you can *use* the friend function before it is declared."

Comment: @Praetorian I agree with you, but what about §7.3.1.2/3? Would it need an amendment?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil In other words, the section is about matching up friend function declarations with the particular function being made a friend.  It has absolutely no impact on when you can and can't call the function being made a friend.

Comment: No, cdhowie's explanation is correct. The clause you're quoting is not concerned with where you make use of the name, it only talks about where the declaration may appear so a *later* unqualified lookup may find it.

Comment: @cdhowie You convinced me. I'll accept an answer from you, based on your comments. Thanks.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Anton's answer is spot on, no need for me to duplicate his, unless you would like my (long-winded) explanation documented in an answer.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil I went ahead and added an answer that tries to dispel the confusion directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, clang is doing the right thing.  This is not a bug.

You are misreading the context of this spec excerpt.  The only thing this paragraph is communicating relates to how friend function declarations and their target function get associated with each other.  *It has nothing whatsoever to do with the usual rules around **calling** that particular function, and changes nothing in that regard.*

Compilation therefore does not fail because the prototype of the function `f()` has not yet been declared at the point you attempt to use it (and instead it finds the typedef with the same name).

If you alter your code to implement the `A::g()` member outside of the class, you will note that compilation fails when the `f()` prototype appears before the implementation and succeeds when the prototype appears after it -- exactly what you would expect to happen if the friend declaration was absent.

Answer (score 1):

In the same paragraph you cited (`§7.3.1.2/3`) there is an example clarifying the lookup rules:

```
// Assume f and g have not yet been defined.
void h(int);
template <class T> void f2(T);
namespace A {
    class X {
        friend void f(X); // A::f(X) is a friend
        class Y {
            friend void g(); // A::g is a friend
            friend void h(int); // A::h is a friend
            // ::h not considered
            friend void f2<>(int); // ::f2<>(int) is a friend
        };
    };

    // A::f, A::g and A::h are not visible here
    X x;
    void g() { f(x); } // definition of A::g
    void f(X) { /* ... */} // definition of A::f
    void h(int) { /* ... */ } // definition of A::h
    // A::f, A::g and A::h are visible here and known to be friends
}
```

So the compiler works correctly.